# tensorflow and keras - fast inference in production from SQS

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, amazon-sqs

I have my model written and trained in Keras. I'm trying to use it for inference in production. I receive SQS "task" messages containing a tuple of `(path_in, path_out)`.

I can obviously use:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 10
batch_messages = []


while True:
  while len(batch_messages) < BATCH_SIZE:
    msg = sqs.read_messsage()  
    batch_messages.apend(msg)

  assert len(batch_messages) == BATCH_SIZE
  batch = np.array([read_image(msg.path_in) for msg in batch_messages]) 

  output_batch = model.predict(batch)

  for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
    write_output(output_batch[i], path=batch_messages[i].path_out)

  batch_messages = []
```

The problem with that is that the code wastes most of the time reading from SQS, reading the image from disk and writing it back at the end. This means the GPU is idle during all this time.

I'm aware of Keras' `Sequence`, but not sure if it is intended for that case as well, and for inference (and not training)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Tensorflow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving) solution as it implements a server side batching strategy which optimizes the inference speed and GOU utilization. Also if you'd like to speed up your pipeline, you should convert the model into a [TensorRT](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-developer-guide/index.html) model which optimizes the models operations to a specific GPU (and it does a lot more).